# Convert a long string to List<string[]> in C#

Tags: c#, string

The string looks like this:

```
"c,c,c,c,c,c\r\nc,c,c,c,c,c\r\n.....c,c,c,c,c\r\n"
```

This line works:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> lineFields = File.ReadAllLines(sFile).Select(line => line.Split(','));
List<string[]> lLines = lineFields.ToList();
```

But let's say I'm not reading from a file, and instead of it I have the string i described before.

What's the fastest **(I refer to preformance)** way to convert it to a List<> of string[] that looks like

```
List<string[]> lLines = [ [c,c,c,c,c] , [c,c,c,c,c] , ... [c,c,c,c,c] ]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you allready use the fastet way with split.

Comment: Asking for the fastest way to do that may not give the results you expect, as performance will depend on the length of the string, among other things. Are you prepared to benchmark the code in all the answers you will receive?

Comment: Use some benchmark. Use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var list = "c,c,c,c,c,c\r\nc,c,c,c,c,c\r\n.....c,c,c,c,c\r\n"
    .Split('\n')
    .Select(s => s.Trim().Split(','));
```

Comment: This works great too.
If we are into performance, what do you guys suggest?
(My dataset is too small to compare it ATM)

Felipe's answer or this one?

thanks.

Comment: @Mockingbird - see above comment

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
// replace \r\n to ; and split it... it will be your lines
var lines = text.replace("\r\n", ";").Split(';');

// split every item of the line arrays by , and get an new array to each item
List<string[]> arrays = lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToList();
```

Comment: works like a charm! thanks!
BTW, is there anyway to skip the replace line in order to improve performance?

Comment: Doing a replace like this will be way slower on  large data-set - as you'll have to create & assign a whole string in-memory of the initial string - albeit with the replaced chars. So - if a 100meg initial string - this will require at least 200meg to process.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
string combindedString = string.Join( ",", myList );
```

Comment: I think OP wants to create `List<string[]>`

Comment: @Yanshof, Sergey is right. I want to create     List<string[]>